# Modifying jQuery checkbox plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to customize [this](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/) jQuery plugin. There is a `type` JS variable. [On this page](http://erayalakese.com/so/) if checkbox is ON , `type` will be XML , else `type` will be XLS. I don't have any idea how can i do it.

If you help me, i'll be glad. Thanks !

Comment: *quickly answers before felix*

Comment: @Shredder: I see everything :P ;)

Comment: I suggest you provide your code as well, I can't find a `type` variable anywhere.

Comment: Yes there isn't, yet . I want to create it according to selection of checkbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hardly related to the plugin. You just have to bind an event handler to the element, check its status and updated the variable accordingly:

```
var type = 'XSL';

$('#yourCheckbox').change(function() {
    type = this.checked ? 'XML' : 'XSL';
});
```

I recommend to read some [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) to get familiar with jQuery and its possibilities.